# How to build OpenSSL 1.1.0 on new system versions?

Tags: ubuntu, openssl

I'm trying to build OpenSSL 1.1.0 on Ubuntu 22 and running the config.

```
Operating system: x86_64-whatever-linux2
"glob" is not exported by the File::Glob module
Can't continue after import errors at ./Configure line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./Configure line 17.
"glob" is not exported by the File::Glob module
Can't continue after import errors at ./Configure line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./Configure line 17.
This system (linux-x86_64) is not supported. See file INSTALL for details.
```

I found this [hint](https://derrylab.com/index.php/2022/08/01/problem-when-building-old-openssl-version-on-the-new-system/) but even though I changed it, I couldn't understand what I should do after using build.info, anyone can help me?